# Magento 2 - Magento 2 - Why is less file loading first? Need it to load after css files

Tags: magento2, css, less

I am using grunt/M2 & I noticed my less files are loading before my css files in my Magento 2 website. Any ideas? I need the less file to load last so it overwrites classes.

Here is what's in my `theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<head>
<css src="css/local-m.css" />
<css src="css/local-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
<css src="css/source/_custom.css" /> <!-- This is the less file -->
</head>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension available that will let you pass an order when adding your custom CSS file.

https://github.com/quickshiftin/mage2-ordered-assets